# Not able to read file in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am facing the issue with this code:

```
<?php

$files = scandir("D:/Dummy");
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filenam = $file;
    $path_to_file = $filenam;
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

    echo "Hello ".$filenam;
    $printFileName="";

    if(strpos("9222339940", $file_contents) === false)
    {
        $printFileName=$filenam." ";
    }
}

echo $printFileName;    
?>
```

Basically, I have written this code to scan all the files in the directory and from the each file, I need to replace the mobile number. But for some reason, I'm not able to run the script. It is throwing error:

> file_get_contents(name of the file) failed to open stream. No such file or directory error.

Comment: Well to aid you into resolving your "for some reason" issue, first check that your $files has something useful in it. What do you see when you var_dump($files) after you've assigned it? Are they all files or files and folders. What does php.net say about scandir?

Answer (score 1):

The [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function of PHP will only return the basenames of the files within the directory. That is, if your directory D:\Dummy contains a file test.txt, then **scandir() will not return the full path D:\Dummy\test.txt, but only test.txt**. So the PHP process will not find the file, because you need to provide the complete path of the file.